# Float left bug in Firefox when when parent is absolutly positioned?

Tags: css, firefox

I have an unusual layout requirement but Ive got it working in Chrome, Edge and IE11, only Firefox doen't work making me think it could be a bug with the browser.

Here is how the page should look:
[image]

But this is how it looks is Firefox:
[image]

Update: I also got this working on Chrome without `float: left` and instead using `width: fit-content`, however this and `width: -moz-fit-content` still don't work on Firefox.

The floated div with the red boarder doenst appear to be floated at all. As a result the blue box is off screen.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  background: grey;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  min-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.col-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col1-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: -2000px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.content:after {
  content: "";
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="col col-1">
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <p>Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="col1-inner">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580152040915-ad6ceeaeb8c1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3450&q=80" />
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/_j_i_m_fb_/pen/GRgaKQE

Comment: It is floated, but it seems that in Firefox, the `.content` expands itself to the full width of its parent element, in this case `.col1-inner`. Since `.col1-inner` has a `right` property of -2000px, the container ends up being over 2k pixels wide, and the blue box gets centered right in the middle of that, which is outside of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

#### Lame answer to the actual question

This is an edge case due to the large fixed units used. Chrome is collapsing the div when float is used. Firefox is not. To determine which browser is technically correct we must look at the appropriate specification. How boring is that... instead, here is a...

#### ... possible solution for what you desire

I have created an alternative example with [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid).

#### HTML

Simple layout. The body is used instead of an extra div, with two divs for the left and right column:

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <p>Contents</p>    
    </div>               
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/3450x2300" />
    </div>
</body>
```

#### CSS

The body:

```
body {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: auto auto; 
}
```

- Establish the grid.
- Create two equal width columns

The content div:

```
.content {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 400px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
```

- Establish the inner grid
- Vertically center the contents
- Use appropriate max and min widths
- Instead of `justify-items: end`, the left `auto` margin provides the horizontal centering. This is so the background doesn't stretch all the way to the left.

The image div:

```
.image {
  position: relative; 
  max-width: 700px;
  min-width: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, grey 0, grey 50%, transparent 50%); 
}
```

- Position the pseudo-element in relation to this div
- Restrict the width of the image so it doesn't get too large
- Restrict the width of the image so it doesn't get too small
- Create the background colour with a gradient that covers only a percentage of the image div

The img is contained like so:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
```

- Restrict width of image to parent div
- Pad out as desired

#### Example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 400px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, grey 0, grey 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.image::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id bibendum enim. Integer blandit arcu lobortis, ultricies quam vitae, elementum urna. Nunc a mauris ex. Aenean egestas neque urna, eu euismod massa ultrices sit amet. Praesent imperdiet
    dictum ante, quis viverra nibh volutpat eu. Sed tempor, quam in molestie tincidunt, eros massa condimentum arcu, ut tempus mauris ligula et arcu. Donec nec faucibus neque, sit amet tincidunt nulla. Nullam et mattis ipsum. Sed euismod porttitor justo
    eu aliquet. Sed hendrerit finibus dignissim. Morbi id ipsum imperdiet, fringilla urna posuere, fermentum justo. Mauris eleifend, orci et eleifend consectetur, augue lacus hendrerit diam, eget dictum lacus sem vitae augue.</p>
</div>

<div class="image">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/3450x2300" />
</div>
```

Comment: I need the image's height to be defined by the height of the content in the right hand column so this doesn't currently work. Change the image to be something like 3450x2300 and you'll see what I mean: https://imgur.com/a/rSOTniw